# Update data in a listbox from another form

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that maintains student scores. I've created a class called students that stores the data and displays it in a list box. Once the user clicks Add a new form (`frmAddStudent`) loads that allow them to add the user by name and their scores and display it in the list box in the main form. It also allows the update/delete functions. I can successfully add students to the list and edit them, but when I press the ok button in the update students form I get the error

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index'

I looked up that this means its thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method, but not sure how it applies here. My value I enter when updating is within range.

Source code below

https://github.com/Triptonix/Student.git

frmUpdateStudent.cs

```
private void UpdateButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)  //open update form for current student
{
    Student Form1 = new Student();
    Form1.Name = StudentName.Text;
    parentForm.UpdateStudent(index, Form1);
    Close();
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

public Student GetStudent(int id)  //Get student index
{
    return studentList[id];
}

public void UpdateStudentList()
{
    students.DataSource = null;
    students.DataSource = studentList;
    students.DisplayMember = "Name";
}

public bool UpdateStudent(int originalIndex, Student studentToEdit)
{
    try
    {
        Student student = GetStudent(originalIndex);  //select index of student
        student.Name = studentToEdit.Name;  //name of student
        studentList.RemoveAt(originalIndex); //remove the student at the index selected
        studentList.Insert(originalIndex, student); //insert new student at index.
        UpdateStudentList(); //update student list
    }
    catch { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Student.cs

```
public class Student
{
    public List<int> Scores = new List<int>();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool AddScore(int score)
    {
        try
        {
            Scores.Add(score);
        }
        catch { return false; }
        return true;
    }
    public List<int> GetScores()
    {
        return Scores;
    }
    public int GetScoreAt(int index)
    {
        return (int)Scores[index];
    }
    public int GetScoreTotal()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int score in Scores)
        {
            sum += score;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public int GetScoreCount()
    {
        return Scores.Count;
    }
    public int GetScoreAverage()
    {
        return GetScoreTotal() / GetScoreCount();
    }
    public void DestroyScores()
    {
        Scores = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

**frmUpdateStudent**

```
public partial class frmUpdateStudent : Form
{
    private Form1 parentForm;  //main form
    private Student studentToEdit; //student list
    private int index; //index

    public frmUpdateStudent(Form1 parentForm, int index)  //update parent form (Form1) with the new student and scores
    {
        this.parentForm = parentForm;
        this.index = index;
        studentToEdit = this.parentForm.GetStudent(index);

        InitializeComponent();

        StudentName.Text = studentToEdit.Name;
        UpdateScoreDisplay();
    }

    public void AddScoreToStudent(int value) //add score to current student and display in the list
    {
        studentToEdit.AddScore(value);
        UpdateScoreDisplay();
    }

    public void UpdateScoreAtIndex(int id, int value)  //update a score selected from the list
    {
        studentToEdit.GetScores()[id] = value;
        UpdateScoreDisplay();
    }

    public int GetScoreAtIndex(int id)  //get the score index
    {
        return studentToEdit.GetScoreAt(id);
    }

    private void UpdateScoreDisplay()  //update the score display list
    {
        CurrentScores.DataSource = null;
        CurrentScores.DataSource = studentToEdit.GetScores();
    }

    private void AddScoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //open the add score form
    {
        frmAddScore addScoreForm = new frmAddScore(this);
        addScoreForm.Show();
    }

    private void RemoveScoreButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //remove a score from current index and update display list
    {
        studentToEdit.GetScores().RemoveAt(CurrentScores.SelectedIndex);
        UpdateScoreDisplay();
    }

    private void ClearScoresButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //clear all scores
    {
        studentToEdit.DestroyScores();
        UpdateScoreDisplay();
    }

    private void CloseButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();  //close form
    }

    private void UpdateButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)  //open update form for current student
    {
        Student Form1 = new Student();
        Form1.Name = StudentName.Text;
        parentForm.UpdateStudent(index, Form1);
        Close();
    }

    private void UpdateScoresButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmUpdateScore updateScoreForm = new frmUpdateScore(this, CurrentScores.SelectedIndex);
        updateScoreForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some missing details. `parentForm.UpdateStudent(index, Form1);` - we can't see where `index` comes from and we can't see the `UpdateStudent` method which is where the problem is happening. Somewhere in that method you're trying to get an item from a collection using an index, but that index represents a position that doesn't exist in the collection. Set a breakpoint at that spot in the code. Look at the index value you're using and then see how many items are in the collection. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'll add the update method, but I also included the source code to save some space.

Comment: It's important to just include the relevant code. That way someone can see the part where the problem is without having to download anything else. It also helps to keep the question self-contained... but we're still missing `parentForm.UpdateStudent`. It's calling that method and that's where the exception is, but I don't see that method.

Comment: Its at the top of frmUpdateStudent. I added it.

Comment: I'm literally searching the text of this page for `UpdateStudent`. There's no method here called `UpdateStudent`.

Comment: Sorry, I added it in Form1 now.

Comment: `UpdateStudent` calls `GetStudent`. `GetStudent` does `return studentList[id];`. Set a breakpoint right there. What is the value of `id`, and how many items are in `studentList`. 100% certain you will find something unexpected there.

Comment: students.SelectedIndex is -1. It's the index of the listbox.

Comment: When you get to the `GetStudent1 method, is id -1? If so, that 's the problem. If there's one item in the collection then the only index is 0. If there are two, the indexes are 0 and 1. If the collection is empty then any value will throw that exception. But there will never be an item with index -1.

Comment: Yes, the value is empty until the user adds a student. They press add from the main form then it loads a new window and lets them add to the listbox in the main form. So once the update form loads its not selecting the index anymore? Even though you have to select it in order to press update? Once you select a user from the list and press update it shows in the Name textfield and presents the right scores. I figured that means it was selected.

Comment: Unfortunately I've gotten as far as I can go. At this point we're into debugging the app, and there's a lot to that.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. If you have the time download my solution I've included and see if you notice anything else.  I've been stuck on this for a couple days and I'm going to continue to work on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the index of my list was -1 when I was trying to call it. I set the SelectedIndex as a local variable then called it. I guess the selected index had to be checked before I could execute it. This the code I fixed.

```
private void students_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {

_selectedIndex = students.SelectedIndex;

if (_selectedIndex > -1)
{

Student student = GetStudent(_selectedIndex); //select index from list

Student students = GetStudent(_selectedIndex); //select index from list
ScoreTotalTextBox.Text = student.GetScoreTotal().ToString(); //show Score Total to box
ScoreCountTextBox.Text = student.GetScoreCount().ToString(); //show Score Count to box
ScoreAverageTextBox.Text = student.GetScoreAverage().ToString(); //show Score Average to box 
}
}
```